# How to find Tickets I worked on during a given timespan?

Tags: sql, hp-alm

We are using HP ALM 12.53.193 for issue tracking.

For a progress report of our development activity, I am trying to find out what tickets I worked on within the past month. Primarily, this includes tickets for which my user name was added to the *Editors* field, or that were marked as *Fixed* or *Closed* by me in the given timespan.

I am seeing some promising hints in [this forum post](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/SQL-Query-to-Find-the-Date-when-the-Defect-Status-is-moved-to/td-p/968360) that uses SQL to query the `AUDIT_LOG` table. Likewise, [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13960/how-to-filter-history-events-of-defects-in-hp-alm) [sqa.se] post suggests an SQL script for an Excel report.

Unfortunately, when I click *New Business View Excel Report* in ALM, I am *asked to upload* an Excel file for some reason, so I am not sure how to proceed from there to entering my SQL.

I have also tried creating a report with the *New Project Report* command (i.e. I am also ok with a non-scripted solution, if that is the way to go in ALM). However, it seems I can only show the filtered contents of single tables (e.g. Defect) there (the "Cross Filter" feature does not let me choose another entity (e.g. the Audit Log) for cross-filtering my defects with).

**How can I retrieve that data from ALM?**

*I am not entirely sure SO is the right site for this question, although I consider HP ALM a "software tool(...) commonly used by programmers". Please migrate if it is deemed a better fit for another site.*